# VLC snapshot with full time index

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to manually thumbnail a bunch of videos, basically picking multiple thumbnails at key points in the video.  I need the thumbnail to have the full timestamp of the video, e.g. something like 00:01:43.033.  But it also needs to be quick, so a minimum of steps, since there are a lot of thumbnails to generate.  I need to be able to stay in the video player and quickly seek and capture with only a few keystrokes.

With VLC I have so far managed to set the snapshot prefix using $T but it doesn't include the millisecond.  So for instance if I try to snapshot at t=00:01:43.033 and again at t=00:01:43.0967, the second snapshot overwrites the first!  Manually adjusting the filename isn't an option.

How can I do this?